# MS Deploy & IIS6 - 401 Unauthorised Error

Tags: tfs, iis-6, msdeploy, msdeployserviceagent

I'm trying to get TFS to automatically **publish** (not package at the moment) my web app on a build to a Win2k3 server with IIS6. The remote agent service is started.

The build fails giving me a 401. I'm now trying to manually run a cmd line from the build server itself (just incase the MSBUILD was doing something strange with the params set on the build definition) and it's giving me the same thing. Here is the command I'm trying to run:

```
msdeploy.exe 
-source:contentPath='C:\Builds\1\Test\DummyTFSWebApp Submission Build\Binaries\_PublishedWebsites\DummyTFSWebApp' 
-dest:contentPath='Default Web Site',
      computerName='http://ipm-vm-dev/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE',
      userName='Domain\AdminUser',
      password='Password',
      authType='basic', 
      includeAcls='False' 
-verb:sync -allowuntrusted
```

But like the build report, it's giving me:

[image]

I can't understand why! The username & password provided is an Administrator on the destination machine. I've even made the build server machine and admin (clutching at straws), and I've made the destination folder a share for everyone with write permission.

Help appreciated as this is really frustrating me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the authType='NTLM' and it now works!

```
   /p:AuthType=NTLM
```